# /usr/bin no longer in path after booting into windows 7

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, login-screen

I have a dual booted windows 7 / ubuntu 14.04 computer.  Everything in ubuntu worked fine until I booted into windows and then switched back to ubuntu.  Now when I try to login it keeps sending me back to the login screen.  I logged in using the command line fine, but it appears to be a messed up path variable.  On the command line I cannot use sudo or any other functions unless I do an export path.

I created a new user, which worked until I had to switch into windows again, then it did the same thing.

Comment: Windows can't mess linux like the default path. It's jsut that you are dropped in limited shell like initramfs because ubuntu does not boot correctly.

Comment: Type in `grep PATH ~/.bashrc` in a terminal window and see if the `/usr/bin` is in the line.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying that it is looping at the login prompt, that is the password shows no errors but returns you to the login prompt. I might be able to help. It happened to me. I don't know why.

[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop?newreg=862ed6cf233f49fdbb8d622b945b89a4)

might help.

The code `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` entered in the terminal is what did it for me. Apparently, some problem in .Xauthority file.
I hope the link helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your `.profile` file, located in your home directory, i.e. `/home/yourusername`or `~`, using `sudo gedit ~/.profile`, it actually says, which files are used by your login shell.

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
          . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

PATH=/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
```

(Typing `echo $PATH` in your terminal would have also given you the value of the `PATH`variable.)

I neither have a `.bash_profile` nor a `.bash_login` file, therefore the command interpreter of my login shell - which is bash - executes my `.profile` as stated in the file. (Find out what your shell is by using `echo $SHELL`. Should the output be different from `/bin/bash`, you may be interested in in this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88201/whats-the-best-distro-shell-agnostic-way-to-set-environment-variables)

Even though it says in the `.profile` file above `include .bashrc if running bash`, my `.bashrc`file is empty, for example.

Therefore I included the paths to the directories of my commands like `/usr/bin` directly in the `.profile` file.

If `/usr/bin` is not included in the value of your `PATH` variable, defined in your `.profile` file, just add it after the other paths using a colon. The order of paths does not matter.

Part of the reason why this happened to you after booting into your other OS is because changes like permanently deleting or adding a path take only effect after reboot. So, as @solsTiCe already mentioned, Windows cannot mess with your system. "Something" else must have changed the `PATH` variable.

[path](/questions/tagged/path) [paths](/questions/tagged/paths) [.profile](/questions/tagged/.profile) [login](/questions/tagged/login) [loop](/questions/tagged/loop) [14.04](/questions/tagged/14.04)